# Dynamic Variable names Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, dynamic

I keep hearing about how I should use arrays and objects to accomplish having dynamic variable names. I'm not sure how to get this to work with my current project.

I need **dynamic variable names for html boxes**, and dynamic names **for scores entered**. How do I accomplish this with my current code?

Below is the Javascript prompt for each of the 5 separate scores for each player.

```
var hole1 = prompt("Enter Hole 1 score:");
var hole2 = prompt("Enter Hole 2 score:");
var hole3 = prompt("Enter Hole 3 score:");
var hole4 = prompt("Enter Hole 4 score:");
var hole5 = prompt("Enter Hole 5 score:");
```

Below here is declaring a variable to **store all of the 6 boxes** that will **hold the scores, and the score total.**

```
var makeScoreBoxes ='<input type ="text" placeholder="Hole 1" id="hole1" /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Hole 2" id="hole2" /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Hole 3" id="hole3" /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Hole 4" id="hole4" /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Hole 5" id="hole5" /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Total Score" id="totalScore" />'
newdiv.innerHTML = makeScoreBoxes;
ni.appendChild(newdiv);
```

It then adds them all up here and stores the total inside of the totalScore variable:

```
totalScore = parseInt(parseFloat(hole1) +
             parseFloat(hole2) +
             parseFloat(hole3) +
             parseFloat(hole4) +
             parseFloat(hole5));
```

It then takes hole1, hole2, hole3, hole4, and hole5, and the sum of them all, and puts them all in my index.html input boxes like this:

```
addTotal = document.getElementById('totalScore').value=totalScore;
addhole1 = document.getElementById('hole1').value=hole1;
addhole2 = document.getElementById('hole2').value=hole2;
addhole3 = document.getElementById('hole3').value=hole3;
addhole4 = document.getElementById('hole4').value=hole4;
addhole5 = document.getElementById('hole5').value=hole5;
```

hole1, hole2, hole3, hole4, hole5, all are fashioned to prompt the user, asking what their score was. And then puts them all in html input boxes all with the same id as the variable, hole1, hole2, hole3, holr4, and hole5. Since there ill be multiple people entering scores, how to I generate/iterate dynamic names for each html box id and javascript prompt variable so I can add up as many scores in as many boxes as I want?

Comment: This is an XY problem. Use an array, not separate variables.

Comment: Sorry I'm sorta new to JS, haven't done too much with arrays. So just store the entries in an array and take iterations and put them in the boxes, and repeat?

Comment: Might be worth a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify all your code to this:

```
var holePrompts = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    holePrompts[i] = prompt('Enter Hole ' + (i + 1) + ' score:');
}

var totalScore = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    totalScore += parseFloat(holePrompts[i]);
}

document.getElementById('totalScore').value = parseInt(totalScore);
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {    
    document.getElementById('hole' + (i + 1) ).value = holePrompts[i];
}
```

Or even shorter if you don't do any other operations on scores:

```
var totalScore = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    score = prompt('Enter Hole ' + (i + 1) + ' score:');
    document.getElementById('hole' + (i + 1) ).value = score;
    totalScore += parseFloat(score);
}
document.getElementById('totalScore').value = parseInt(totalScore);
```

Quick side note, as you are new to JavaScript. When you are working with arrays and you are using `i` to print message. Pay attention to brackets: `'Enter Hole ' + (i + 1) + ' score:'`.

If you will type it like this: `'Enter Hole ' + i + 1 + ' score:'` it will output *Enter Hole 01 score:*, *Enter Hole 11 score:*, *Enter Hole 21 score*, and so on. It's because of order of operations. When number is added to string it's converted to character and concatenated.

Comment: Why `holePrompts = {}` and not `holePrompts = []` if your using numeric indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Use object literal notation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

```
var scoreByHole = new Object();
scoreByHole['hole1'] = document.getElementById('hole1').value;
scoreByHole['hole2'] = document.getElementById('hole2').value;
```

...and so on. Then you can reference the object later like so:

```
var firstTwoHoles = scoreByHole.hole1 + scoreByHole.hole2
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small jsfiddle to explain how arrays work:

```
var data = [];
var enteredValue = 1;
var i = 0;
while (enteredValue) {
    enteredValue = prompt("Enter score of hole " + ++i);
    if (enteredValue) {
        data.push(parseFloat(enteredValue));
    }
}

var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + parseFloat(data[i]);
}
alert("Entered score of " + data.length + " holes. Sum is: " + sum);
```

First we create a new array `[]` in the variable `data`. Next we have a while loop, which will be repeated everytime you enter a value. If you press cancel or enter nothing the while loop will be canceled.

Inside of the while loop, we trigger the prompt and if it contains a value, we push this value to the array `data`. If we enter some values the array may look like this:

```
[1, 2, 1.5]
```

In the last step we sum all the contents in the array using a for loop and output the result. Other programming languages like PHP have an `array_sum()` function, which does the same what the for-loop does now. But javascript doesn't have such function native included.

To address the single values in an array we may use a key. In arrays a key is an integer beginning with zero. So the first value in this array got the key 0. The second one, the key 1, ...

The for-loop does that for us, beginning with zero and ending with 1 number lower then the length of the array is. Because in the example above the array contains 3 values. The `data.length` would be 3. But the key of the last item is 2 (because it starts to count with zero, not with one).

Here you'll find the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fXgv4/1/

I hope this helps you understanding how to work with arrays in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to use an array to make this work, just use this code:

```
window['your_variable_name']
```

And it will return the contents of that variable.

You can set variables using this method too.

Answer (score 0):

If you need "let" instead of "var", you can't get it from the window object.

you can use **eval**

This is an example :

```
let a1 = "string 1";
let a2 = "string 2";

let i = 1;

console.log(eval(`a${i}`));// output: "string 1"
```